# How to embed text and pass in php

Tags: php, curl, discord

I am working with php and Discord,Right now whenever i enter "/ping" then chatbot giving me
response "pong!"(static message) which is working fine,But i want to embed this msg and then pass,How can i do this,Here is my code which can "embed in discord"

```
 $url = "MyDiscordWebHook";
    $headers = [ 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8' ];
    $POST = ['content'=>'Pong!'];
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($POST));
    $response   = curl_exec($ch);
```

And Here is my code which is "reply to user" (!pong),Just want to embed "description" (!pong),How can i do this ?

```
    $discord->on('ready', function ($discord) {
        $command = new Command($discord, ['name' => 'ping', 'description' => 'pong']); // need to embed "pong"
        $discord->application->commands->save($command);
});
```

Comment: It is very unclear what do you want to achieve

Comment: Unclear how these two bits of code relate to each other, or what you want to do where, or what you mean by "embed" in this context. Plesase [edit] the question to give a better explanation. Remember we can't see the rest of your code, or look at your screen, or read your mind to know your full intentions. See also [ask] for more guidance. Thanks,

Comment: @leo : 1) in first section i mentioned how to embed "content" (which is working)
2) in second section i want to know how can i use/embed instead of static message "pong"

Hope you understand now

Comment: what exactly do you mean by when you use the word `embed`?

Comment: Doesn't clarify anything for me either. In both cases you're already just specifying static data in the code.

Comment: @ADyson: In Discord we have to "embed" message before send so thats why i want to embed "description" ( yes right now static text) , so that i can work further, hope you understand my point

Comment: @leo we have to embed this code ( according to discord documentation) , only then we can work further (receive message or any other work)

Comment: No it's still not clear what is meant by "embed" really. Do you mean how to use a variable instead of static text? Or is it something specific to discord's data structure? I've tagged discord now as well in your question in case anyone with experience of that product specifically can make sense of your request.